# What is the native equivalent to jQuery's "$.fn.has"?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What's the native equivalent of jQuery's [`$.fn.has`](https://api.jquery.com/has/)?

For example, how would you write the following code:

```
$("li").has("ul").css("background-color", "red");
```

In vanilla JavaScript?

**NOTE:** This question is about the `has` function and not the `contain` function.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier with CSS?

Comment: Certainly, but that's not an option in my use case.

Comment: @DA. CSS doesn't have any kind of parent selector

Comment: [jQuery's source is on github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/56136897f241db22560b58c3518578ca1453d5c7/src/traversing.js#L27) you can see how they do it by going through the source files

Comment: This is what I could think of: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("li")).filter(parent => Array.from(parent.querySelectorAll("*")).find(child => child.matches("ul")));`, then a `forEach` for the CSS.

Comment: Why did someone down vote my question? whats wrong with it?

Comment: @ViniciusSantana You haven’t provided an attempt of your own or shown any research effort of your own, for example.

Comment: @Xufox I'll be happy to share what I tried, but I don't have anything else relevant or working. I posted a clear question with all context necessary for someone to properly answer it. I like to think that we should add to people question and not subtract. Thanks for the answer though. I'm not gonna debate this here. I'm actually looking for a solution. If you don't have one, thanks for the negativity. :)

Comment: @MikaelLennholm ah! You are right...I was reading that backwards. Not so easy to do with CSS after all. :)

Comment: @ViniciusSantana Why negativity? I didn’t even downvote and provided something to start with. The possible reasons for a downvote are all included in the tooltip on the voting arrow: _“This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful”_.

Comment: @Xufox I'll take it back them. I thought you were justifying your downvote.

Answer (score 3):

I would basically do it the way the jQuery specification for `.has()` describes it, i.e. filtering the collection by trying to select the required element from the descendants of each element:

```
var liElements = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("li"));
var liElementsThatHaveUl = liElements.filter(function(li) {
  return li.querySelector("ul");
});

liElementsThatHaveUl.forEach(function(li) {
  li.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since i don't use jQuery, I can not make not sure if `has` selects all `<li>` elements which are direct parents of `<lu>` elements (like CSS selector `li > ul`) or selects all `<li>` elements having `<lu>` elements under (like CSS selector `li ul`). Chose the one you like;

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("li ul")).reduce((r, e) =>
  r.length ? (r[r.length - 1] === e.parentElement ? r : r.concat(e.parentElement)) : r.concat(e.parentElement), []
);
```

Thanks [@Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar)'s comment for the clarification.

Comment: `$("li").has("ul")` means select all `<li>` for which `li ul` would return something.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an extremely late answer but here is an updated version of [Lennholm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2236921/lennholm)'s answer.

```
const has = (selector, sub) => {
  const matches = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(selector));
  return matches.filter(match => match.querySelector(sub) !== null);
};

has("li", "ul").forEach(li => {
  li.style["background-color"] = "red";
});
```